# Elastic Beanstalk Worker Scheduled Task invalid date

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My `eb deploy` is failing with the following error:

> Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Failed of parsing file 'cron.yaml', because: invalid date - (AWS::EB::SQSD::ScheduleParser::ScheduleFileError)

I have narrowed it down to this line of cron config:

```
 - name: "twice_monthly"
   url: "/tasks/twice_monthly"
   schedule: " 15 7 1,15 * *"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the leading space in the schedule.  It works if you change it to this:

```
   schedule: "15 7 1,15 * *"
```